# Git/GitHub - change default location for cloned repository without changing HOME variable?

Tags: git, github

I'm still learning Git and GitHub and I haven't been able to figure this out so far. I found a public repository on GitHub that I wanted to try editing, so I forked the repository and then cloned it so I'd have a local copy of the files to work with. I had to search for a while online to figure out where exactly Git puts the local files, but I ended up finding the files in their respective subfolders under C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub (I have Windows 7 -- for other versions of Windows the files are apparently in C:\Documents and Settings\< current_user>).

When setting up GitHub I was able to select a repository location, but apparently that location only affects repositories I create, not repositories I clone. I wanted to try and figure out a way to change the default cloned directory location, but it sounds like the only way to do this is to change the HOME environment variable. However, changing an environment variable that could also affect other programs does not sound like best practice so I'm hoping there's another way.

I found one way to do this by simply specifying the desired path every time I enter a clone command, like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/example.git c:/other/path/to/repo
```

Is there a way to do this without modifying the HOME environment variable and without typing it out every time (which invites typo errors), or is specifying the location in the command line probably the best way?

EDIT: I'm using the GitHub for Windows GUI and Powershell.

Comment: Are you using the GitHub for Windows GUI? Or are you cloning through the bash shell?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the GitHub for Windows GUI and the shell tool that comes with it, Powershell. It seems to have nearly the same functionality as `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Open up the UI, hit **Tools**, then **options...** and change the **default storage directory**.

Comment: Ahhhh, that's it! I opened up the Tools before and didn't see it, but apparently that menu does not show the option to change the default storage location unless I open it on the Dashboard. Yay thanks!! Only one problem - I can't mark this as the answer when it's a comment ...

Comment: Ah, my mistake, Powershell is a separate command line program - it's not part of the GitHub Windows GUI.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can still run Git from Powershell (or I might be confusing that with Cygwin).

Comment: Yes, I cloned these repositories using Powershell, so it seems to work just fine.

Comment: The way to do this now is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68474257/4549682

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you're using the GitHub for Windows application, so you can configure it within the settings dialog. Hit <kbd>Alt-T</kbd>, press **options** and then you can change the **default storage directory**.

Comment: That worked! And after changing the default storage directory, I simply moved the cloned repositories I'd already downloaded to the new default location, and then used the option under Tools > Options to discover new repositories on my harddrive. It immediately found the two clone repositories I just moved and linked them up. Thanks!

Comment: This was an obviously important core feature for basic useage of the app, so ... of course they deleted it :(. The setting no longer exists (also 'Alt-T' appears to have been replace, there are no menus mapped to that shortcot). This answer was correct years ago but doesn't work any more

Answer (score 3):

Git will by default clone into a new subdirectory of the current directory, so you could simply set up whatever shell/terminal you're using to start in the `C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub` directory by default. If it's the regular `cmd.exe` prompt, you should be able to configure this in the properties window of the shortcut you're using to open it.

Comment: How would I configure the shortcut to open the directory I want? Make a shortcut to cmd.exe on my desktop and then in the Target line on the Properties window do something like this? `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "cd C:\Windows\"`

Comment: @AliumBritt: It's been a while since I used Windows, but I believe there used to be a field named "current directory" that you could set.

Comment: how to change the default direcory for cloned repository @hammar using bash shell

Comment: @MalikAsif if you don't already have a .bashrc file in `%userprofile%`, make one. just `cd $userprofile` then `echo d>.bashrc`, then open .bashrc in a text editor, remove the letter d, and paste this in, and modify as-needed: `gdd='/c/path/to/mydefault/dir'` then paste in `gcl(){
cd $gdd && git clone $1
}`

The just use the terminal with gcl githubURL
So something like `gcl git@github.com:defunkt/github-gem.git`
Would work. Make sure to use linebreaks in the bashrc file with that function's curly braces, or it will throw errors.

Comment: Yes that (in above comment) was the solution to my problem. Had done it long long time ago :-) Thank you @kayleeFrye_onDeck

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of SourceTree, the **default storage directory** is no longer a named option; but it has been renamed as ***Project Folder***.

**Tools >> Options >> General >> Repo Settings >> Project folder**