# Git clone default save directory

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I just stated using and learning Git, when using `git clone example.repo` it saves it in `C:\users\Alexander\example.repo`.

I would like to change the default saving directory to `F:\Work Station\Git - Github\`, which is my HDD for All Web developer files, and also the default directory accessed by VS Code\Studio.

How do i change it? And also is it permanent? For all future repo clones?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764913/git-github-change-default-location-for-cloned-repository-without-changing-home)
was the reason i decided to post my question. 
Reading it, i get a feeling its for another tool, 
i am using git console and git GUI the originals.
I want to learn the basics before moving on to a simplified, custom Git GUI

```
git clone https://github.com/username/example.git c:/other/path/to/repo
```

This command doesn't do anything at all.
Also Pressing Alt+T in the Git also nothing.
Options? tools? all i find is add or remove tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git/GitHub - change default location for cloned repository without changing HOME variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764913/git-github-change-default-location-for-cloned-repository-without-changing-home)

Comment: Git does not have a "default saving directory". If you run `git clone <url> <path>` it puts the clone in the specified path. If you run `git clone <url>` it puts the clone in a name located in `.` (the **current** directory) that is constructed from the URL. For instance, the URL you quoted above would use `./example` as the target of the clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no path is specified `git clone example.repo` will create a new folder in the current directory called "example". If you wish to put the repository elsewhere you may navigate using the change directory command: `cd`.

From the info you have given and assuming you are using Git Bash since you tagged your question with it, I would run `cd /F/navigate-to-your-desired-location`, then run `git clone example.repo`. Please note that Git Bash works similar to Unix and may see your HDD as a directory (folder). Best of luck!

Comment: I was posting the answer and then i saw your comment.
I apply the answer to you, cause had i saw earlier it would have saved me.
i cant even find inside the site, were can i see my questions.. grrr
ahh... i had missed that...The frustrations of a noob.....

Answer (score 1):

After a while by mistake i found it.

```
git clone
```

I entered the command blank and it showed me the examples and..

```
git clone "https of the repo" "F:/Work Station/<name>/"
```

You need to place it inside "", also the last path needs to specify ether to an excising empty folder, or you place your own name of the folder that will be created, and it will contain all the repositories files inside.

I am happy to figure this by luck. Still a lot to learn.
Thanks to all.