# GitHub Desktop - how to change default storage directory?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I am using GitHub Desktop on Windows, and want to change the directory where cloned repositories go by default (currently `%USER%\Documents\GitHub\`).

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764913/git-github-change-default-location-for-cloned-repository-without-changing-home) from 8 years ago in which OP is using the GitHub for Windows GUI, but that's apparently not the same as GitHub Desktop because none of the answers work for me. `Alt-T` does nothing, and I can't find *default storage directory* in global options or in repository settings. Also, the shortcut to GitHub Desktop starts in a different directory altogether, so modifying that would be no use.

I know that I can use the command line to `git clone` to any directory, but it would just be nice if one could configure the desktop version to do that as well.

Does anyone know of a way to change the default directory for cloned repos that works in the current version of GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible from the menus right now: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2889

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to do this now is to change the folder when cloning it in the GUI:

[image: GUI choose folder]

Click on the repo to clone, then change the initial path in the 'Local path' area. After that, it should use that location as the default. Any easy way to get the folder you want is to copy it from the address bar in a file browser:

[image: file browser bar]